# How many and which solutions does this linear equation have?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, number-theory

Suppose we are given two non-negative integers $n$ and $k$ and we look for solutions to the equation
$$
x_1+x_2+x_3+\dots+x_k=n
$$
where the unknowns $\{x_i\}$ are also non-negative integers.
How many solutions are there and how to number them?

Starting with $n=0$ there is one solution, $a_i=0$. Moving on to $n=1$ we have a single $a_i=1$ and all others zero.
How to continue this, induction perhaps? I'd try but I don't have the general solution.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)

Answer (score 1):

A very intuitive way to think about this is the following. Suppose you’re going to the grocery store to buy fruit. Now you want to buy $n$ fruits of $k$ different kinds of fruit. Say $x_1$ is the amount of bananas you buy $x_2$ the amount of oranges etc.

Now I’ll represent each different combination of fruits as $xx|xxx|…|x$ which means you have bought $2$ bananas (the amount of $x$’s to the left), $3$ oranges (the amount of $x$’s in the second spot) and then finally $1$, say apple. That is we have $x_1=2$, $x_2=3$, …, and $x_k=1$. This is equivalent to choosing where the $k-1$ lines $|$ sits, among the $n+k-1$ symbols, so $\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$ different ways.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Now is there a way to index those solutions?

Comment: You can use alphabetical order $000n$, $001(n-1)$, $002(n-2)$,...,$00n0$, $010(n-1)$, $011(n-2)$, ... $01(n-1)0$, $020(n-2)$,..., $0n00$, $100(n-1)$, ... , $n000$.